# MapboxGL.MapView zoomLevel not working (for react-native version)

Tags: react-native, mapbox-gl

I am trying to zoom the mapview in MapboxGL.MapView , but even though i put zoomLevel={15} or zoomLevel={1} no changes can be seen on the zoom level as the app starts.

I have tried changing the access token of mapbox
I have used different zoomlevels but none seem to work
I also added center coordinates but it also does not have any effect

```
   <MapboxGL.MapView
     ref={(c) => this._map = c}
      style={{flex: 1}}
       zoomLevel={9}
        centerCoordinate={columbusCircleCoordinates}
     >
    </MapboxGL.MapView>
```

No error messages can be seen

Comment: Have you found a solution for this issue?

Comment: Apparently not . But i found the example that worked and edited this according to my needs . https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/tree/master/example

Comment: I reached out to the developer and apparently the zoom level is now set using MapboxGL.Camera https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/issues/198

Answer (score 0):

To follow up what [@iamgraeme posted](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/issues/198), as of version 7.0.0, now you must use the [Camera component](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/master/docs/Camera.md):

```
<MapboxGL.MapView
  ref={(c) => this._map = c}
  style={{flex: 1}} >

  <MapboxGL.Camera 
    zoomLevel={9}
    centerCoordinate={columbusCircleCoordinates}
  />

</MapboxGL.MapView>
```